# Unit testing : avoid actual execution of the async task

Tags: java, android, mockito, robolectric

I am using Roboelectric 3.0 and Mockito to unit test a class.
The class does some work and starts an Async task that has stubbed dependencies so I am getting a runtime exception(during the async task execution).

Is there a way, I can check

1. the Async task was started
2. Avoid executing the Async task.

Comment: You could start by sharing the relevant code & unit test.

Comment: Can you add a code example to illustrate?